# Compose Email without MFMailComposeViewController popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, feedback

I am trying to implement a "Send Feedback" viewcontroller where the user can automatically push to a viewcontroller and start filling out a form - a form that will then be submitted and composed to a static email address.

I am looking at the facebook app under the send feedback view and that's exactly what I would like to do.

Basically limiting the user from editing the Recipients and only able to edit the subject and body, which I will implement as UITextViews or something along those lines.

I understand there is the already implemented MFMailComposeViewController that presents a preimplemented UIViewController that easily allows the user to enter their subject, body, cc targets as well as recipients, but I would like to step away from another viewcontroller popping up and basically implement my own viewcontroller that the user can press on a UIButton and automatically send their typed in subject and body.

Refer to the facebook iOS version "Send Feedback" page.

If there are any further questions please ask.... I'll edit ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do it directly but it is possible via web service. you will need to implement SMTP on server side and the server will send an email instead of you.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. So I'm working with a company who has a web service that has already implemented SMTP. Their web site has the link and everything. Is there a tutorial that shows how to access the SMTP through a objective-c and do what I would like to do?

Comment: So I was able to setup my gmail account and use their SMTP server to get emails from my app... I am only able to get emails from myself, so maybe I'll add a string object that is the users email address and have them enter their address before submitting the app so I can have a reference to who actually sent the email so I can email them back. But thank you very much @Apurv for your response. It was correct :)